# show this expression by relating multiplication to addition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

does anyone know the proof to this expression ?

$\sum a_k = \infty$ $\implies$ $\prod (1-a_k) = 0$

given that $a_k < 1$

I was told taking logs but still cant figure this out.. Sorry that I am a newb
to this.

Comment: Have you a condition $0 \leqslant a_k < 1$?

Comment: That is obviously false without further assumptions on the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Take $a_n=n$, for instance.

Comment: k varies between what and what ?

Comment: yes sorry i missed out the condition that $a_k < 1$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $0\le a_k\lt1$.

Since $1-a\le e^{-a}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^n(1-a_k)
&\le\prod_{k=1}^ne^{-a_k}\\
&=e^{-\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}=0$, we get
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\infty\implies\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-a_k)=0
$$